# How do I incorporate font and transparency in my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I have to do a webpage from scratch for a project, and I know absolutely nothing about HTML. I just started creating my navigation bar. How do I change the font to centhury gothic? and how do I add transparency to the background. It'd also be really helpful if you could tell me how I can change the "home" page to a logo that links you to the home page. Thank you very much in advance to anyone helping!!! So far I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
          background-color: grey;
      }
      li {
          float: left;
      }
      li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 34px 85px;
          text-decoration: none;
      }
      li a:hover:not(.active) {
          background-color: #grey;
      }
      li a.active {
          color: white;
          background-color: #4CAF50;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Social">Social</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Comercial">Comercial</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Sobre el fotógrafo">Sobre el fotógrafo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Contacto">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: font-family , for font. And transparent color use rgba. rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) is white 50% visible.

Answer (score 0):

To change the font to century gothic use:

```
font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
```

To Make the home button an image you can use:

```
<img src="Image.png" height="" width="">
```

Lastly to make the background transparent use rgba (It supports alpha):

```
background-color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/kgbcwqns/), I haven't tidied up your code but this could give you a head start.